# How to swipe after updated to appium 1.7.x

Tags: java, appium

```
public static void swipeDown(MobileElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)AppiumDriverCapabilitiesUtilities.driver;
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
        scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId());
        js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
    }
```

I have update appium to version 1.7.x, earlier i was using 1.4.x there swipe functions are done using Touchactions class, but i dont knew how to do it after update to version 1.7.x

Comment: What is your question? What is your specifc problem? please explain more and not just a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

to scroll in new appium you should use

```
touch.longpress(x-cordinat,y-cordinate).moveto(x-cordinat,y-cordinate).release().perform;
```

to get the cordinate of the element you can use.

```
element.getLocation().getX();
```